# Website link, image, description not working on facebook

Tags: facebook

I don't know what's wrong lately with my website. Since Yesturday and facebook is not displaying my URLs as normal.

Usually when I share a link, I can see the featured image, the title and the description. But now I have this. Which is pretty bad.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/C1fyW.png

What can we do?

Thanks a lot

Comment: What is the url to that you shared? My guess is that you are missing og-tags

Answer (score 0):

Always when debugging what FB shows use [FB Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/) - it allows you to see what's happening and what should be fixed. I recommend using "*Fetch new scrape information*" button, which forces Facebook to scrape URL once again. This will result in most accurate report on what's wrong.

Your problem is:

> Object at URL 'http://www.formulawahad.com/reports-results/41525/' of
>   type 'article' is invalid because the given value '193476057363271'
>   for property 'fb:admins' could not be parsed as type 'fbid'.

I suppose you entered your fanpage id as "admins", and you're not allowed to do that. In admins section you are only allowed to enter fb_uids of **users** (**not** fanpages, **not** apps) that manage the site. Read about it [in Facebook docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/insights).

Comment: Thanks a lot. Actually, I had the "social media" attributes disabled, so I activated it to see if that's fix the problem but it's the same. I didn't enter anything. I just installed ALL IN ONE SEO and it did everything to me! But I guess the latest update has a problem, it broke my sharing on facebook :(